# Where do I find the Google Drive icon?

Tags: windows-7, icons, path, google-drive

I made a custom link to my Google Drive directory on the Windows 7 Professional application bar. Now I'd like to change that icon, so that it's obvious it's the Google Drive folder.

How do I find the Google Drive icon?

Comment: Your question isn't all that clear.  Please considering clarify your question.  Its not clear if your asking how to simply change the icon of the folder or asking specifically how to select the Google Drive icon.

Comment: @Ramhound: duDE fix the problem ;)

Comment: Just clarify the question, I want to upvote the question, but I can't upvote questions that are not crystal clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find the installation folder of Google Drive and the executable `googledrivesync.exe` (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe`).

Right click -> Properties -> Change Icon

Answer (score 3):

Since most Windows versions and Windows programs have moved or will move to 64-bit, this icon can now be found here. Take note, the icon displayed on the `.exe` is (probably) the one you're looking for, but that `.exe` contains a dozen or so icons if you choose it as a source, just like most do.

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe
```

If you happen to still be on a 32-bit system (doubtful), then as duDE said above, it will be:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only can select image format (png, jpg....) create a desktop.ini file

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
InfoTip=Tu carpeta de Google Drive contiene los archivos que sincronizas con Google.
IconFile=C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe
IconIndex=15
```